# Setting cache lifetime on collections

Tags: cache, collection

I would like to know how we can control the cache lifetime on a collection.

Here's how I initialize caching on my collection:

```
public function _construct() 
{
    ...

    // Configure collection cache
    $this->initCache(
        Mage::app()->getCacheInstance(),
        'MY_COLLECTION',
        array(Namespace_Module_Model_Something::CACHE_TAG)
    );
    parent::_construct();
}
```

Where the cache instance comes from `Mage_Core_Model_Cache`. I can see how its frontend model is created out of `Zend_Cache_Core` -- whose class provides a cache lifetime setter. But this does not appear to solve my problem.

I'm using APC caching on the backend, and *that's* what I want to modify when the cache entry is written. And I'd like to be able to control this *per* collection (as in the constructor shown above).

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I figured it out. Was simpler than I expected.

The clue came out of `Mage::app()->saveCache()`, which is simple a wrapper method for the cache model's save routine:

```
$this->_cache->save($data, $id, $tags, $lifeTime);
```

When I noticed the `$lifeTime` parameter, it dawned on me that the `save` method accepts a fourth param * facepalm * -- well, hopefully this helps someone.